# Tracked Raycast in RealityKit

Tags: swiftui, realitykit

I'm trying to implement a feature using **SwiftUI** and **RealityKit**, in which a series of 3D objects placed in space (such as cubes or spheres) are automatically detected using a continuous raycast that emanates from the center of the device and hits the nearest 3D object at every moment.

I've tried using this method:

```
@MainActor
func trackedRaycast(
    from point: CGPoint,
    allowing target: ARRaycastQuery.Target,
    alignment: ARRaycastQuery.TargetAlignment,
    updateHandler: @escaping ([ARRaycastResult]) -> Void
) -> ARTrackedRaycast?
```

but I haven't been able to find a solution in any way. Could someone please help me understand how to implement this feature?